# Why does the hashNavigation component in Swiper replace the entire path in the URL?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to enable deep-linking to images in a Swiper carousel. The "hashNavigation" component seems to be purpose-built for this but I can't see how to make it work. When I enable it and provide the `data-hash` attribute in my slides it replaces the entire path with the hash I provided. Obviously, this renders it useless for any swiper not on the home page. How can I get it to *append* the hash to the path instead of replacing it? Here's my code instantiating it:

```
var vis = document.getElementById('vis'),
swiperOpts = {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  mousewheel: true,
  hashNavigation: {
    watchState: true,
    replaceState: true,
  },
  autoplay: {delay: 4444}
},
swiper = new Swiper(vis, swiperOpts);
```

And a markup sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<base href="/">

<link rel="preconnect" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="//unpkg.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
</head>

<body class="visio">
<main>
<div class="swiper-container" id="vis">
<ul class="swiper-wrapper">
  <li class="swiper-slide" data-hash="235" style="">
      <p>slide one</p></li>
  <li class="swiper-slide" data-hash="228" style="">
      <p>slide two</p></li>
  <li class="swiper-slide" data-hash="224" style="">
      <p>slide tre</p></li>
  <li class="swiper-slide" data-hash="227" style="">
      <p>slide for</p></li>
  <li class="swiper-slide" data-hash="236" style="">
      <p>slide fiv</p></li>
</ul>
        </div>
    </main>
<script src="//unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Here are some examples of the URLs I'm seeing:

- base URL: `domain.com/visio/sol`
- slide data-hash value: `224`
- URL after Swiper modifies: `domain.com/#224`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague; it would help to see the HTML and the URLs that you're seeing. However, if you're using hash-based navigation (i.e., `https://yoursite.com/#/path/goes/here`), there's no way to have "two hashes". Either the hash is your path, or the hash is something else (in this case, the Swiper hash value).

Comment: @mattbasta I added some markup to my question. The path and the hash (fragment) are two distinct parts of a URI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL
I'm not attempting to use two hashes. The hash that should be appended to the path is replacing the path instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to get this to work properly but I worked around it with the following code:

```
let initIDX = 0;
if(window.location.hash){
    let lmnt = document.querySelector('[data-hash="'+window.location.hash.substring(1)+'"]'),
    i = 0;

    while((lmnt = lmnt.previousSibling) != null) if(lmnt.nodeType == 1) ++i;

    initIDX = i;
}

var vis = document.getElementById('vis'),
    swiperOpts = {
        loop: true,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        initialSlide: initIDX,
        on:{
            slideChangeTransitionEnd: function(){
                history.replaceState(null, null,
                    window.location.pathname + '#' + this.slides[this.activeIndex].dataset.hash);
            }
        }
    },
    swiper = new Swiper(vis, swiperOpts);
```

This is working for me.